# AWS CDK Java - Template format error: Mappings element count 0 should be greater than 0

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I would like to use AWS CDK with Java to create one simple VPC, with a public subnet, a security group and a EC2 instance. The Java class is the following, very simple:

```
public class CDKStack extends Stack {
public CDKStack(final Construct scope, final String id) {
    this(scope, id, null);
}

public CDKStack(final Construct scope, final String id, final StackProps props) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // Create public subnet
    SubnetConfiguration publicSubnet = SubnetConfiguration.builder()
            .name("public-subnet")
            .subnetType(SubnetType.PUBLIC)
            .cidrMask(24)
            .build();
    List<SubnetConfiguration> subnetList = new ArrayList<>();
    subnetList.add(publicSubnet);
 
    // Create VPC with subnet above
    Vpc vpc = new Vpc(this, "vpc-from-ckd", VpcProps.builder()
            .cidr("10.0.0.0/16")
            .maxAzs(1)
            .subnetConfiguration(subnetList)
            .build());

    // Create the Security Group inside the VPC
    SecurityGroup securityGroup = new SecurityGroup(this, "sg-cdk-java", SecurityGroupProps.builder()
            .vpc(vpc)
            .allowAllOutbound(true)
            .build());
    
    // Create image and EC2 instance
    final GenericLinuxImage genericLinuxImage = new GenericLinuxImage(Collections.emptyMap());

    Instance.Builder.create(this, "EC2 from CDK")
            .instanceType(new InstanceType("t2.micro"))
            .machineImage(genericLinuxImage)
            .securityGroup(securityGroup)
            .vpc(vpc)
            .build();
  }
}
```

Though, when I run `cdk deploy` (on Windows 10) I get the following error that I do not understand:

```
CDKStack: deploying...
CDKStack: creating CloudFormation changeset...

 ❌  CDKStack failed: Error [ValidationError]: Template format error: Mappings element count 0 should be greater than 0
```

Any help that could clarify what I'm doing wrong would be really appreciated, as I am going through samples and API documentation, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

After some more search, I paid more attention to the error message and realized that *Mappings* refers to the [Cloudformation Mappings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/mappings-section-structure.html#mappings-section-structure-examples) (sounds obvious now that I think about it, but from the error message it is absolutely not clear, it seems more a verb in a sentence) and from their example in the official doc I thought it could be related to the environment variables.
So, I set them explicitly in the Java class and now it works:

```
.env(Environment.builder()
    .account("1234567890")
    .region("aws-region-name")
    .build())
```